# How to pass input type to php function on the same site without action form?

Tags: php, linux, forms, apache, input

I am trying to execute simple code in table like this:

```
<td><input type="text" name="val1"></input>
<td><a href="' . doSomething($val1) . '" class="link-button">Test</a></td>
```

How to pass val1 variable without action form without any GET or POST in the same page just to execute function after click and stay on the same site after clicking?

Is it even possible to do it like that?

Comment: pass what variable into where?

Comment: input variable (val1) what user fill in into a href doSomething function after click ...

Comment: without reloading a page you have to involve javascript to do it

Comment: can I just use some reload command in php or html after clicking on a href maybe?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not possible:

- PHP is executed on the *server*
- HTML is interpreted on the *client*
- HTTP works thru *request*ing the server, which then *respond*s

If you understood these basics you'll see yourself what you want is impossible. Using either a HTML FORM or AJAX is irrelevant, as both end up performing a GET request and your question states you don't want that. https://www.php.net/manual/en/faq.html.php might help distinguishing the scopes.

Comment: Yeah I thought so. I was just wondering if there is any workaround or something. Thank you.

Comment: No cheats available, you have to play the game as intended.